# When hook_field_info_alter is invoked?

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying drush cc all, but no luck.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_info_alter/7

I need to programmatically hide a field and thinks that this is place to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's invoked in several places. It happens in [`_field_info_collate_types()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/_field_info_collate_types/7), which is called from

- `field_info_cache_clear()`
- `field_info_field_types()`
- `field_info_formatter_types()`
- `field_info_storage_types()`
- `field_info_widget_types()`

So there's a fairly large surface area for invocation.

`hook_field_info()` is for providing metadata about fields, though, so using it to programatically hide a field is doomed to failure. You simply don't have that option in the info hook.

Depending on what you mean by "hide" you'll either want to implement a form alter hook (to remove a field from a form), or a preprocess/view hook to hide it from being rendered, or maybe both. Obviously YMMV if you mean something other than those options.

Comment: I mean set programmatically what is possible to do via Manage Display -> Format (hidden)

Comment: You'll need to ask that as a separate question, it's not related to what you've asked (which is simply where the hook is invoked from)